# Firebug hotkey to toggle command line/editor

Tags: firebug

Firebug 1.10.3

Is the default hotkey available to switch between the command line and the command editor? Otherwise, how could it be configured?

Answer (score 1):

here [Keyboard and Mouse Shortcuts](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Keyboard_and_Mouse_Shortcuts) and [Firebug Preferences](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Preferences) you will get the all shortcut key

Comment: Thanks. What i know is pressing `Ctrl+Shift+L` to get focus on the command line, but no luck on the command editor.